# twitter bootstrap make from source

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to "build" twitter bootstrap from source git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git and I git clone it to my local machine.

Obviously, on my local machine, I have had nodejs and npm installed and the required node packages less and uglify-js installed as well. And all node modules are in my system path so "lessc" and "uglifyjs" commands are available in my terminal.

Going into bootstrap's root directory, I run "make" and this is the output:-

```
(luc)calvins-MacBook.local ttys002 Fri Feb 03 10:51:29 |~/work/luc/static/bootstrap|
calvin$ make
mkdir -p bootstrap/img
mkdir -p bootstrap/css
mkdir -p bootstrap/js
cp img/* bootstrap/img/
lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
lessc --compress ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
lessc ./less/responsive.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.responsive
lessc --compress ./less/responsive.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.responsive
cat js/bootstrap-transition.js js/bootstrap-alert.js js/bootstrap-button.js js/bootstrap-carousel.js js/bootstrap-collapse.js js/bootstrap-dropdown.js js/bootstrap-modal.js js/bootstrap-tooltip.js js/bootstrap-popover.js js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js js/bootstrap-tab.js js/bootstrap-typeahead.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
uglifyjs -nc bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
zip -r docs/assets/bootstrap.zip bootstrap
updating: bootstrap/ (stored 0%)
updating: bootstrap/css/ (stored 0%)
updating: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css (deflated 85%)
updating: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css (deflated 84%)
updating: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.responsive (deflated 76%)
updating: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.responsive (deflated 79%)
updating: bootstrap/img/ (stored 0%)
updating: bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png (deflated 4%)
updating: bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png (deflated 4%)
updating: bootstrap/js/ (stored 0%)
updating: bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js (deflated 82%)
updating: bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (deflated 74%)
rm -r bootstrap
lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > ./docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css
lessc ./less/responsive.less > ./docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
node docs/build
cp img/* docs/assets/img/
cp js/*.js docs/assets/js/
cp js/tests/vendor/jquery.js docs/assets/js/
cp js/tests/vendor/jquery.js docs/assets/js/
```

What should I do next to include my css files in my html page?  I don't see where the built/created bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.min.responsive files are located. The only thing that seemed to have changed is that a "bootstrap.zip" was created, as seen by running git status above.

```
(luc)calvins-MacBook.local ttys002 Fri Feb 03 10:51:35 |~/work/luc/static/bootstrap|
calvin$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   docs/assets/bootstrap.zip
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not an expert on this by any stretch of the imagination (just started to play around with Twitter bootstrap as well), but I get a similar output as you when I just run `make`. However, if you run `make bootstrap` it generates a folder entitled `bootstrap` that contains the compiled css as far as I can tell:

```
make bootstrap
mkdir -p bootstrap/img
mkdir -p bootstrap/css
mkdir -p bootstrap/js
cp img/* bootstrap/img/
lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
lessc --compress ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
lessc ./less/responsive.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
lessc --compress ./less/responsive.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
cat js/bootstrap-transition.js js/bootstrap-alert.js js/bootstrap-button.js js/bootstrap-carousel.js js/bootstrap-collapse.js js/bootstrap-dropdown.js js/bootstrap-modal.js js/bootstrap-tooltip.js js/bootstrap-popover.js js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js js/bootstrap-tab.js js/bootstrap-typeahead.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
uglifyjs -nc bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

The  new `bootstrap` directory (`bootstrap/bootstrap`) contains the following:

```
bootstrap/css:
- bootstrap-responsive.css
- bootstrap-responsive.min.css
- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.min.css

bootstrap/img:
- glyphicons-halflings-white.png
- glyphicons-halflings.png

bootstrap/js:
- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.min.js
```

This might be an issue with the documentation, leaving out the correct command, but I'm not sure. My memory of how a `Makefile` works is if you issue `make` without a target, it defaults to the first target in the makefile. In this case, that target is `docs` instead of `bootstrap`.

I think you can then just copy the contents of the new bootstrap directory to wherever you would normally put the css/js assets for your project.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment about how `Makefile` works when `make` is issued without a target clarifies my uncertainties. Appreciate it.

Comment: Is `make` still relevant with the new versions of Bootstrap ? Seems like we have to use [`grunt`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#compiling-css-and-javascript) now don't we ?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for an alternative to `make` for building Bootstrap (especially since `make` is not Windows friendly), there's a [build system for Bootstrap with Grunt.js](https://github.com/jgallen23/grunt-bootstrap)

For the most part it produces the same results as the `makefile`. The grunt-contrib-qunit task will add better support for qunit/phantomjs when grunt 0.4.0 is released (found here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit) . Until then you can still work with the built in Grunt tasks for testing.

Comment: this is outdated and probably doesn't work anymore. I'll report back if I have time to get it updated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be handy for some of you. See Readme for usage/options. Its a simple batch to compile up bootstrap from source on Windows. https://github.com/chazelton/bootstrap. You can also just grab "make.bat" if you like and drop it in your downloaded source. It is forked here  for convenience. Basic usage below

```
C:\projects\bootstrap>make (would create sub dir "build" with css, js, img dirs)
C:\projects\bootstrap>make -c (combines bootstrap/responsive to one file)
C:\projects\bootstrap>make -l (outputs source less files under css dir)
```

See additional options in readme on GitHub...

NOTE: requires UglifyJs and Less to be installed via npm globally so => npm install less -g. The batch will prompt you if these are missing. However you'll need to install them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have gnuwin32 installed and on my path, and I've `npm install`-ed `uglifyjs`, `recess`, and `jshint`.  I then made the following additions to the top of the Makefile:

```
SHELL=c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe
MKDIR=mkdir.exe -p
UGLIFYJS=uglifyjs
RECESS=recess
JSHINT=jshint
```

The first line (SHELL=) fixes this problem:

```
w:\github\bootstrap>make bootstrap
mkdir.exe -p bootstrap/js
make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x4227d3)
```

the second line (MKDIR=) is to prevent the dos mkdir command being used (which doesn't understand the `-p` flag).

Then a global search/replace on all the executable references:

```
-       mkdir -p bootstrap/js
+       $(MKDIR) bootstrap/js
        cat js/bootstrap-transition.js js..
-       ./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs -nc...
+       $(UGLIFYJS) -nc bootstrap/js/boot..
etc.
```

Now `make bootstrap` finishes without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

You should download some node packages first

Try

```
sudo npm install recess
```

and then

```
sudo npm install jshint
```

Then use

```
make bootstrap
```

in the directory of the MakeFile