# Compiling Twitter Bootstrap after cloning from github - where is the output?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [twitter bootstrap make from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123112/twitter-bootstrap-make-from-source)

I am trying to understand how to build Twitter Bootstrap.  It seems that there are two ways to access Twitter Bootstrap.

The **first** is to download a `bootstrap.zip`, available from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip and then unzip it, which results in the following directory structure:

```
.
└── bootstrap/
    ├── css/
    │   ├── bootstrap-responsive.css
    │   ├── bootstrap-responsive.min.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   └── bootstrap.min.css
    ├── img/
    │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
    │   └── glyphicons-halflings.png
    └── js/
        ├── bootstrap.js
        └── bootstrap.min.js

4 directories, 8 files
```

If I understand correctly, all I would have to do is drop the `bootstrap` directory and all the files underneath it, into my project directory and then, in my HTML file include a tag something like the following: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="location_of_my_twitter_bootstrap_file" />`

The **second** way to get Twitter Bootstrap is to clone the github project and then to use `make` to build it.  I have installed `Node.js` and I have used `npm` to install several packages, such as `less` `jshint` `recess` `uglify-js` and `connect`.  When I run the `make` command from the bootstrap directory it seems to work and I get the following output:

```
##################################################
Building Bootstrap...
##################################################

Running JSHint on javascript...             ✔ Done
Compiling LESS with Recess...               ✔ Done
Compiling documentation...                  ✔ Done
Compiling and minifying javascript...       ✔ Done

##################################################
Bootstrap successfully built at 09:36AM.
##################################################

Thanks for using Bootstrap,
<3 @mdo and @fat
```

However, I don't get a bootstrap directory with the same directory structure that unzipping the zip files gives me.  Instead, a bunch of files under `bootstrap/docs/assets` are updated, and they don't seem to correspond to the files I get from bootstrap.zip (there are many more of them, for instance).

My question is: what advantage does cloning the github project offer, what is the purpose of using `make` as I did, and how can I cleanly generate CSS and JS files from Twitter Bootstrap source files that I can link to from my project?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9123112/1478467

Comment: That question you linked to is from 8 months ago and things have changed since them.  When he ran `make` a `bootstrap.zip` was created which contained the `bootstrap` directory.  I'm not getting that zip file created when I run `make`.

Comment: Still, your answer is very close to the one there, even after 8 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was that I was just running the `make` command.  After looking closely at the `Makefile` I realized that I needed to run `make bootstrap`.  (Running `make` by itself defaults to `make build`.) Once I ran `make bootstrap`, a `bootstrap` directory was created that contained the expected files.