# Make not recognized when running npm install of Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, makefile, npm

I installed the GitHub Windows interface to access my Github account. As a start, I cloned the Twitter Bootstrap repo from GitHub by using the below command

```
git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
```

Then I ran `npm install` to download the dependencies. But when I try to run commands like 'make' or 'make test', I get the following error

> The term 'Make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: why don't you try the http://windows.github.com/ ? It's easier to use.

Comment: @sulfureous Two things. First, the original poster's problem has nothing to do with the fact that he's using Git from the command line, it's building Twitter bootstrap, which is an issue unrelated to Git. Second, I ***do not*** recommend GitHub for Windows. Out of all the Git GUIs I have ever used (TortoiseGit, SourceTree, Git Cola, Git Extensions), it is in my opinion the most difficult to use. Besides, I argue that ***if you want to have an acceptable degree of proficiency in Git, then you must learn to use it from the command line***.

Comment: @cupcake. I disagree, it's pretty easy to use, and i dont agree with you on having to learn from the command line as a must. I understand if i misunderstood the question, and since you seem more skillful on the subject why don't you answer the question so we can all learn as much as you. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this ["Build Twitter Bootstrap on Windows"](http://codethatworks.blogspot.fr/2012/05/build-twitter-bootstrap-on-windows.html) blog post, and make sure your "make.bat" is:

- either in your current directory
- or in your `%PATH%`

With `make.bat`:

```
@echo off
rd build /s /q
mkdir build\img
mkdir build\css
mkdir build\js

copy img\* build\img

call .\node_modules\.bin\lessc -x less\bootstrap.less > build\css\bootstrap.min.css

copy /B js\bootstrap-transition.js+js\bootstrap-alert.js+js\bootstrap-button.js+js\bootstrap-carousel.js+js\bootstrap-collapse.js+js\bootstrap-dropdown.js+js\bootstrap-modal.js+js\bootstrap-tooltip.js+js\bootstrap-popover.js+js\bootstrap-scrollspy.js+js\bootstrap-tab.js+js\bootstrap-typeahead.js build\js\bootstrap.js

call .\node_modules\.bin\uglifyjs --ascii bootstrap\js\bootstrap.js > build\js\bootstrap.min.js
```

---

If this doesn't work, check out "[twitter bootstrap make from source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511431/6309)", in particular the project:

**["`Make.bat`" Build Bootstrap for Windows](https://github.com/chazelton/bootstrap)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the make.bat from last link https://github.com/chazelton/bootstrap, and I keep getting this error "The system cannot find the path specified. Please install less using npm install less -g". In Make.bat, it is failing this condition even when the file exists "IF NOT EXIST %npm%\lessc.cmd"

Comment: @fn79 you could try and install GoW to see if that helps. Gnu on Windows includes `less.exe`. https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow

Comment: In the new bootstrap v3.3.7, "bootstrap-" is removed from all js files so rename them in bash before using it.